# Children element attribute - link href - jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am having a trouble in getting href attribute of an a link within the table.

```
<table border="1" align="center" width="90%" id="choose-address-table">
<tr><td>Header</td><td> Effective Date</td><td> Header</td></tr>
<tr><td><ul><li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Text (1)</a></li></ul></td><td>01-01-2013</td> <td> <input type="button" class="SelectorButton"  name="Request Print" value="Request Print"/></td></tr></tabl>
```

JS

```
$(".use-address").click(function () {

         var link = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").children().children();
         var link1 = $(this).find('a'); alert(link1.attr('href'));
         //             alert(link.html());
         //             alert(link.text());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your posted markup has the class `use-address`. Assuming you are trying to select the table:

```
$('#choose-address-table').click( function() {
    var link1 = $(this).find('a');
    alert(link1.attr('href')); // alerts correct value
});
```

Comment: I have got the solution, Actually I am trying to find the link details inside tr, where in a button inside td. on button click traverse through the elements inside tr and finding the a link details. Your answer also correct..

Comment: The other way also can be done, the below working code I'm using.

     $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".use-address").click(function () {
             var findlink = $(this).closest("tr").find("a");
             alert(findlink.html());
             alert(findlink.text());
             alert(findlink.attr('href'));});});